# Ошибка при попытке чтения поля объекта из метода класса

Tags: c++

Упрощенно мой класс выглядит так:

```
class Map
{
private:
    int width;
    int height
public:
    Map(int width, int height)
    {
        this->width = width;
        this->height = height;
    }
    int getWidth()
    {
        return width;
    }
    int getHeight()
    {
        return height;
    }
}
```

Остальные поля и методы я опустил за ненадобностью в примере.

Объект я инициализировал в основной форме WinForms следующим образом:

```
private:
    Map* map = new Map(50, 50);
```

По другому инициализировать не получалось из-за ошибки **"Член класса управляемый не может относиться к типу класса неуправляемый"** (при инициализации `Map* map = new Map(50, 50);`)

После этого я вызываю другой, не приведенный здесь метод класса Map, в котором нужно значение поля width, для объекта map и получаю следующую ошибку: **System.AccessViolationException: "Попытка чтения или записи в защищенную память. Это часто свидетельствует о том, что другая память повреждена."**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чем это может быть связано. Моя единственная догадка, что что-то не так с инициализацией, но я без понятия, как это исправить.

Comment: Ну так добавьте то что не привели сюда.

Comment: ну это же не с++, а c++/cli. Поэтому, оно и работает так странно. Переходите на светлую сторону - на обычные плюсы и скорее всего все будет ок